# Can not share image via share kit

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet, sharekit

I am new in iPhone and I want to share text and image using share kit.
I request to provide link or complete tutorial for share kit.

 I am using below to share to share.

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:imageView.image title:@"San Francisco"];
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];
```

It shares only text, but not an image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to show it with the toolbar like the below code

```
  [actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
```

Hope it will be help.